# Sudden error in discord.js: TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

The code down below worked perfectly fine until invited into another server. I don't understand why the error suddenly appeared. I tried switching it to users, but even then, the error persisted. Can anyone help?

```
const imagekill = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
let author = message.member.displayName
let target = message.mentions.members.first()
let user = target.displayName

  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  msg = message.content.toLocaleLowerCase();

  if (target === undefined) {
    if (msg.startsWith(prefix + "kill")) {
      const random = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    
      .setTitle(author + " killed" + msg.split(prefix + "kill")[1])
      .setThumbnail("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/831790854880493621/831792385645084672/image0.jpg")
      .setImage(imagekill)
      .setColor("#E91E63")
      message.channel.send(random)
      console.log("Command sent")
    }
  }
  else {
    if (msg.startsWith(prefix + "kill")) {
      
      const random = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    
      .setTitle(author + " killed " + user + msg.split(target)[1])
      .setThumbnail("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/831790854880493621/831792385645084672/image0.jpg")
      .setImage(imagekill)

      .setColor("#E91E63")
      message.channel.send(random)
      console.log(user);
      
    }
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, target can be undefined.

I've changed getting target.displayName when undefined check is finished:

```js
if(!message.member) return;
if(!message.mentions) return;
const imagekill = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
const author = message.member.displayName
const target = message.mentions.members.first()

if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

msg = message.content.toLocaleLowerCase();

if (target === undefined) {
    if (msg.startsWith(prefix + "kill")) {
        const random = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(author + " killed" + msg.split(prefix + "kill")[1])
            .setThumbnail("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/831790854880493621/831792385645084672/image0.jpg")
            .setImage(imagekill)
            .setColor("#E91E63")

        message.channel.send(random)
        console.log("Command sent")
    }
} else {
    const user = target.displayName
    if (msg.startsWith(prefix + "kill")) {

        const random = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(author + " killed " + user + msg.split(target)[1])
            .setThumbnail("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/831790854880493621/831792385645084672/image0.jpg")
            .setImage(imagekill)
            .setColor("#E91E63")

        message.channel.send(random)
        console.log(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was honestly so confused as to why it wasn't working so suddenly T^T

Comment: Wait, I suddenly got another error. It now says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of null" for const author = message.member.displayName

Comment: your message.member is null. it's better add some guards..

Comment: Ahhhh, thank you again! I'll add in the changes and see how it goes